# How can I add the -ml flag (or any flag, really) to ocamllex in a dune file?

Tags: ocaml, lexer, dune

Here is my current `dune` file:

```ml
(library
(name parsing)
(libraries toto fmt menhirLib)
(modules parser lexer lex_and_parse)
)

(ocamllex lexer)

(menhir
 (modules parser)
 (flags --explain -v))
```

I know it's probably not a great idea to have too big an automaton, but it would be handy for me to be able to debug my lexer in its current state, which implies allowing for greater automata with the `-ml` flag. I haven't been able to provide flags to ocamllex. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `(ocamllex lexer)` with

```
(rule
 (target lexer.ml)
 (deps   lexer.mll)
 (action (chdir %{workspace_root}
          (run %{bin:ocamllex} -q -o %{target} %{deps}))))
;                             ^^^^^^^^
;                       add your flags here
```